# Get the shortest substrings between two multicharacter delimiters

Tags: c#, regex

I have

```
string text = "aa aa value kk 8718764 aa value1 kk kk kk 5178gkjh aathtkhkk";
```

I want to get all texts between `aa` and `kk` and the expected results are:

```
1 = value
2 = value1
3 = thtkh
```

I try using a `"aa(.*?)kk"` regex, but I am not getting the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.*?` will still match `aa` in between `aa` and `kk`.

Use a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37343088/3832970):

```
aa((?:(?!aa).)*?)kk
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or

```
aa((?:(?!aa|kk).)*)kk
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=aa%28%28%3F%3A%28%3F!aa%29.%29*%3F%29kk&i=aa%20aa%20value%20kk%208718764%20aa%20value1%20kk%20kk%20kk%205178gkjh%20aathtkhkk)

**Details**:

- `aa` - an `aa` substring
- `((?:(?!aa).)*?)` - Group 1 capturing any zero or more chars (if `RegexOptions.Singleline` option used, even including newline) that are not starting an `aa` substring sequence, as few as possible
- `kk` - a `kk` substring

[image]

[C# code](http://ideone.com/XPPynj):

```
var re = @"aa((?:(?!aa).)*?)kk";
var str = "aa aa value kk 8718764 aa value1 kk kk kk 5178gkjh aathtkhkk"; 
var res = Regex.Matches(str, re)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(p => p.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Is it possible to explain var re :) it's great answer

Comment: It is actually a tempered greedy token  within delimiters, and the answer I linked to explains it very well. I have added a short explanation here, too.